# Why is platformio bricking my QT-PY ESP32-S2 boards, and can I recover them?

Tags: esp32, adafruit, platformio

I have bricked my Adafruit QT-PY ESP32-S2 and need help recovering it and programming it.

I'm running platformio on Ubuntu 22.04. When initially plugged in to USB, the QT-PY ESP32-S2 showed up as /dev/ACM0:

```
$ ll /dev/serial/by-id
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 60 Nov  7 09:53 ./
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 80 Nov  7 09:53 ../
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 Nov  7 09:53 usb-Adafruit_QT_Py_ESP32-S2_84:f7:03:f6:96:d8-if00 -> ../../ttyACM0
$ lsusb
..
Bus 001 Device 120: ID 239a:8111 Adafruit QT Py ESP32-S2
..
```

I added this to my platformio.ini:

```
monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_port = /dev/ttyACM0
```

After I uploaded a program using platformio (from inside VSCode if it matters) the device no longer appeared in lsusb at all, even after USB reinsertion.
After resetting the device into DFU mode and running lsusb I see this:

```
$ lsusb
..
Bus 001 Device 119: ID 303a:0002 Espressif ESP32-S2
..
```

I tried two other QT-PY boards and succeeded in bricking those as well. I cannot use ESPTool as it does not show up as a serial port. I tried connecting the QT-PY boards to a machine running Windows 10 with no success. In the Windows device manager it says no driver found.

I still have one unbricked QT-PY ESP32-S2 that I can program from Windows without incident but that's not a long term solution.

Comment: After some digging I installed dfu-util. Running "sudo dfu-util -l" I get the message <Found Runtime: [303a:0002] ver=0723, devnum=124, cfg=1, intf=2, path="1-2", alt=0, name="UNKNOWN", serial="0">  which reassures me that the device is not completely fried.

Comment: You can't brick ESP32's in software (you can program efuses to only allow cryptographically signed software to run but that takes a lot of effort and isn't going to happen accidentally). Whatever's happening, PlatformIO isn't bricking or frying your boards. Press and hold the BOOT button, press and release the RESET button, release the BOOT button.

Comment: Thank you romkey. Per my previous comment, I am able to go into DFU mode so my choice of the word "bricked" was incorrect. Unfortunately I'm still unable use the device.

Comment: Then the problem lies in whatever you're flashing to it. The ROM boot loader will output messages using hardware UART0; if the application crashes before the it runs sufficiently to bring up USB serial then you won't see the device as a serial port (like what's happening here). You can connect a separate USB/serial device like an FTDI adapter to the TX pin (and GND) to check for those messages.

Comment: You are absolutely correct romkey! One of the libraries I was using (NeoPixel) was updated and it caused the lockup. Problem solved!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it fixed!